# Magento 2: Get System->Config value in JS file

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I have a JS file that is loaded through `require-js.config`.
I need to get access to a `store->configurations` value inside my JS file.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Your issue solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we take a look at onepage phtml template, we can see how to set and get a global config Js variable.

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml**

```
...... 
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
        // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
......
```

We can do the same way by setting a global Js variable.

For example, in your template:

```
<script>
   window.valuesConfig = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValuesConfig(); ?>'
</script>
```

And then, in your custom js, you can get:

```
getValues: function() {
                return window.valuesConfig;
}
```

Remember add the method in your block, for example:

```
public function getValuesConfig()
{
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('get/value/config');
}
```

Comment: Technically, yes this is an answer to my question. I'll accept it as the answer. But I was looking for something more elegant than just dumping out global variables for the world to see onto the page.

Comment: As far as I know, Magento 2 also use local storage feature. We can also add the config to local storage.