# override JS based on system configuration

Tags: magento2, overrides

How can I override `Magento 2` core `js` based on system configuration (Yes/No)? For example
Currently I am overriding `checkout` default `js` into my module. And it works fine for me. Now I want to override this based on my system configuration setting. Is there any way to achieve this ?

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default" : "VENDOR_MODULENAME/js/shipping-save-processor-default-override"
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put all overriding code into if condition.

```
if(your condition)
{
    var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default" : "VENDOR_MODULENAME/js/shipping-save-processor-default-override"
        }
     }
   };
}
```

Overriding will work if your condition will true.

Comment: How to get  system configuration value in if condition ?

Comment: use global js object for store configuration value refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125193/magento-2-get-system-config-value-in-js-file